# How to fix Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I got a problem building a UWP project in Visual Studio Community 2017. On building I get the error:

> Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: An item with the same key has already been added.

This is a project being built against Fall Creator's Update in VS, and worked fine this morning on Creator's Update.

I've updated VS to the latest version, I've restarted, I've cleaned/rebuilt the project.

This is happening at build time, not run time.
Does anyone got any ideas how to fix?

Comment: iIt can be duplicate resource key or a similar problem. Could you try excluding XAML files one by one to see if the problem is in one of them?

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up creating a new project and copying all my .cs and .xaml into it, which resolved the problem.